# How do I calculate the present value of a credit default swap?

Tags: finance, probability, finance-mathematics

I am paid 20 million every time a bond drops to a new low over a 120 month period. I need to know how to find the present value of such an arrangement if there is a continuously compound interest of 5 percent.

Additional information:

The bond starts at a A rating and is only paid the first time it reaches any rating lower than A. So A -> AA-> A-> B->CCC would pay 40 million.

I am given the following probability transition matrix (the probability of the rating on the left becoming the rating on the right):

```
   p[AAA][AAA] = 0.9725; p[AAA][AA] = 0.0275;
   p[AA][AAA] = 0.0020; p[AA][AA] = 0.9742; p[AA][A] = 0.0238;
   p[A][AA] = 0.0020; p[A][A] = 0.9825; p[A][BBB] = 0.0155;
   p[BBB][A] = 0.0073; p[BBB][BBB] = 0.9819; p[BBB][BB] = 0.0108;
   p[BB][BBB] = 0.0030; p[BB][BB] = 0.9783; p[BB][B] = 0.0187;
   p[B][BB] = 0.0010; p[B][B] = 0.9751; p[B][C] = 0.0239;
   p[C][B] = 0.0066; p[C][C] = 0.9852; p[C][D] = 0.0082;
   p[D][D] = 1.0;
```

When the bond reaches a rating of D, the bond defaults and cannot recover from that position thus the swap arrangement is closed and we receive the most money possible at $100 million. Otherwise the arrangement continues until the bond matures at 120 months.

I need to find a fair monthly premium, which I believe involves finding the present value of this arrangement.

Comment: you did not precise the time period over which your proability should be considered.

I give an example :
`p[AAA][AAA]=0.9725` means that if the bond is AAA, then it has 97.25% to stay AAA the next day ? the next month ?

Comment: As MJ73550 mentions, a time period is critical. For the transition matrix, the maturity of the contract, and the bond (if different). 2nd point - who owns the bond and collects the 5% coupon - you?

Comment: Apologies, I'm awful at making sure I include all the information. You own the underlying asset and the bond has a chance of changing ratings a total of 120 times, every month for 10 years. You are collecting the 5% on the bond (semiannual coupons), but I don't believe that is relevant to finding the premium of the swap. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Just curious - why would the coupon not be relevant to the premium?

Comment: You're paying for essentially an insurance plan that operates outside the bond, but is dependent on the bond. We want to know what I should be paying monthly for the swap arrangement. I could be wrong and these things can somehow correlate, but I don't see it.

Comment: For the correlation side, an easy way to see it is to think about a credit default swap on something USD sovereign debt. If they were to default, it's a pretty safe bet that rates are going to change. intuitively it should be easy to see that huge companies are going to be more correlated with the discounting than small ones are - if apple defaulted it would be pretty shocking. If your local grocery store goes kaput, it's not going to have an effect. That's if you're using USD OIS/Libor as collateral. If you're using the bond as collateral, then it's going to be much more correlated.